# How to design my all records?

Tags: html, codeigniter-3

I retrieve the image and display it into the view.but i don't know to popup my images when hover my images.I tried it but every-time image pop up at once hover at once.So how to divided each image into different div's so i can individually make them pop up when hover.Following is my view

```
<?php include('inc/header.php');?>

<div class="main">
    <?php
        foreach ($view as $row) {
            echo "<img src='".base_url()."images/".$row->image."'>" ;   
            }//end for each

    ?>


</div>
<?php include('inc/footer.php');?>
```

and when i add some divs and css

```
<?php include('inc/header.php');?>

<div class="main">

<div id="thumbwrap">


    <a class="thumb" href="#"><?php

            echo "<img src='".base_url()."images/".$view->image."'>";   
            }//end for each

    ?>
    <span><?php
        foreach ($view as $row) {
            echo "<img src='".base_url()."images/".$row->image."'>" ;   
            }//end for each

    ?></span></a>

    </div>


</div>
<?php include('inc/footer.php');?>
```

Please help...

Comment: put your foreach() to the entire anchor tag so that everything comes in a loop

Comment: will you please demonstrate...and thanks for the reply @FairyDancer

Comment: I think you finished your problem if not ping back... Ill explain. Sry for late replay.. @sudeep

Comment: yes..any way thanks